# Selecting element dynamically added

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to asynchronously load data from mysql. First, on page load I add multiple divs to the page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        // Layout
        var main = $("#main-div");
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            main.append("<div class='container'><a href=\"blah\">"+array[i]+"</a><div class='button-container'><span id='playcount_"+array[i]+"' class='playcount' style='margin-right:5%'>nope</span></div></div>");
        }
        // Get info for each sound in array
        for(var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
            $.post("script/php_getinfo.php", { "file": array[i] }, updatePlaycount, "json");
        }
});
```

The `container` divs are added with a `span` with an id of `playcount_A`, `playcount_B`, etc. After the divs are added, a `POST` is made per item in the array and calls `updatePlaycount` upon success.

updatePlaycount attempts to select the element and insert text into the `span`:

```
function updatePlaycount(data) {
    $('#playcount_'+data.name).text(data.playcount);
}
```

The function correctly gets the `data.name` and `data.playcount` fields (for example `A` and `1`), but for some reason jQuery cannot find `#playcount_A`! Surely they've been added already, since there's no loading involved with adding the divs...

Comment: You are calling `array.length` but its nowhere declared in the code?

Comment: Sorry, there's too much code to post here. But like I said, the divs get laid-out properly. The array is just Strings like `A,B,C`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me.  Doesn't seem like that much code to demo.  fiddles can use ajax by the way so if you have a (big) library to include you can do that too

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gillyspy/9QB9r/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Layout
    var main = $("#main-div"),
        array = ["A", "B", "C"],
        updatePlaycount =  function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var $playct = $('#playcount_' + data.name);
                console.log($playct);
                $playct.text(data.playcount);
            }

    function ajaxI(i,arr){
      var J=  JSON.stringify({
                    "name": arr[i],
                        "playcount": (i+1)+''
                });
        console.log(J)
    $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            url: "/echo/json/",
            data: {
                json: J,
                delay: 3
                },
            success:  updatePlaycount
        });
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) {
        main.append("<div class='container'><a href=\"blah\">" + array[i] + "</a><div class='button-container'><span id='playcount_" + array[i] + "' class='playcount' style='margin-right:5%'>nope</span></div></div>");
    } // end for

    // Get info for each sound in array
    for (var j = 0; j < array.length; ++j) {
       ajaxI(j,array);
    } // end for
}); // end ready
```

please send cheque payable to... j/k

Comment: I'll check this out as soon as I can!

Comment: The "delay" parameter doesn't appear to be doing anything. I see it works fine in your fiddle, but I get console spam immediately from `updatePlaycount` when I run it on my site. Do I need to add something to my PHP file?

Comment: this is how you construct an ajax request in jsfiddle with jQuery. the delay parm is helpful in a fiddle to simulate request/response delay.    You will have something like `data : { yourdata }` and `delay` will be irrelevant.  Since you said " function correctly gets the data.name and data.playcount field" and you didn't provide code for your ajax request then you can keep the ajax request however you had it.

Comment: Turns out there were other underlying issues, but your code still helped a lot.. And it's more organized than mine was :P Thanks!